# GeoServer / GeoWebCache serve precached TMS

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tile-map-service

I am pretty new to GeoServer and GeoWebCache

I have a set of precached tiles (TMS) that I want to server via GeoServer / GeoWebCache.

I have saved tiles in C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.13.0\data_dir\gwc

and want to serve them in the following form (as per the TMS structure of the cached data):

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/layername/z/x/y.formatExtension

How do I specify the 'layername' configuration, I think it is in the geowebcache.xml

If so, does anyone have a thorough example that I can follow?

Answer (score 2):

GeoWebCache has currently no support for pre-cached TMS as a tile source, only as an output service.

It would be really easy to develop one though, if you feel like doing it, the source code is here and pull requests are welcomed:
https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache

Comment: Thank you  Andrea Aime.  I am not sure where to start on this, but will have closer look into it.